# Only show label control if there is message to display

Tags: asp.net

I'm a noob to asp and I am trying to show a label control if there is a message populated dynamically, otherwise hide the label. This is basically and error message control.

I have applied a css style to the control with a colored background, so if there is no message to display, the user still sees the blank control.

I know how to do this with javascript, just not sure if it's possible within the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lbl.visible = (lbl.Text.Length > 0);
```

Where `lbl` is the ID of your Label control

Answer (score 2):

On the server side all the controls have a `Visible` property that determines whether they appear on the page or not. You should be able to use it something like the following:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyLabel.Text)
{
    MyLabel.Visible=false;
}
```